# how to send mobile push notification using google firebase

Tags: firebase, moodle

I'm using Moodle framework and I want to send message and notification through firebase any ideas about how to reach that ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself so can't give you instructions

But I believe you can use AirNotifier to push to Firebase

Some documentation from Moodle here

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Moodle_app_notifications

Github for AirNotifier here

https://github.com/dcai/airnotifier/#readme